# Why do I get the error: sh:node command not found if its installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, bash, visual-studio-code

My goal is to run the js file on vscode and I already set up the node path to bashrc and the terminal works pretty fine when I try nodejs on the terminal but when I try to run the .js file I still get the error.

```
[Running] node "/home/ishi/Documents/30 days.../ohnoes.js"
/bin/sh: line 1: node: command not found
```

Any thoughts? I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: After adding path to bashrc, did you do ```source .bashrc```. If that does not work, try ```nodejs /the/script.js```. If still no luck advise what OS you have installed nodejs on, plus how you installed it (i.e. nvm)

Comment: `.bashrc` only sourced when you start bash interactively. Try add this path to .bash_profile or .profile whichever you have.